# How to schedule task and get the response asynchronously?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, completable-future

I don't know if I've used the correct title, but I will try to explain the problem below. 
I have the following method to check the payment status from external service:

```
@Autowired
PaymentService paymentService; 

public void checkPaymentStatus(Payment p){
   // sending 
   String status = paymentService.getPaymentStatus(p.getId());
}
```

It works in main thread and there might be hundreds of requests per second, so I decided to use CompletableFuture to run the tasks asynchronously in separate threads.

```
@Autowired
PaymentService paymentService; 

public void checkPaymentStatus(Payment p){
   // sending 
   CompletableFuture<Response> status = paymentService.getPaymentStatus(p.getId());
}
```

*PaymentService.class*

```
@Service
public class PaymentService{

private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

  @Async
  public CompletableFuture<Response> getPaymentStatus(long id){
    Response results = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Response.class);
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(results);
  }
}
```

Configuration

```
@Bean
public Executor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("payment-service-");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

It works perfectly, but I have another task here. Every request must be wait 30 seconds before sending to the external service.

How to solve this problem?

Update:

**Update:**
In this methods,  I might use Thread sleep, but it is not the correct solution as it blocks the Thread for 30 seconds and next task might run after 60 secs, etc.

```
@Async
  public CompletableFuture<Response> getPaymentStatus(long id){
   // I might use Thread sleep here, but it is not the correct solution as it blocks the Thread for 30 seconds and next task might run after 60 secs, etc.
    Response results = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Response.class);
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(results);
  }
```

Comment: `CompletableFuture.completedFuture()` returns an instance of `CompletableFuture` that has already completed with the specified result. This means that nothing is going asynchronous here.

Comment: You may want to look into [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html.schedule()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#schedule(java.lang.Runnable,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) - that allows you to run a task after a delay

Comment: And, as far as I know, spring should do this for you. When a client makes a request to the web service, spring should allocate one thread to handle that request. If you have 100 simultaneous requests to this method, there should be 100 threads trying to enter this method (i.e. there is no "main" thread here).

Comment: @Jai you missed the `@Async` annotation there. Also, it's not Spring that allocates the threads, it is the application server. There is a dedicated thread pool with a limited number of threads. The more threads you have, the more resources they consume. You don't want to have 100+ threads that are just sleeping – even blocking should be avoided if possible. I would also assume that the OP doesn't want the client to wait for 30s either.